# R, cannot allocate vector of size 1123.5 Gb

Tags: r, manejo-de-memoria, ram

Tengo una matriz de consumo con medio millón de observaciones y 187 variables cuando corro

```
fviz_nbclust(data, kmeans, method = "wss") +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 4, linetype = 2)+
  labs(subtitle = "Elbow method")`
```

me dá el siguiente error

> "cannot allocate vector of size 1123.5 Gb

supongo que es un problema de capacidad de memoria RAM, ¿Qué alternativas tengo para trabajar con esta matriz y que la memoria no sea un impedimento?

Nota: R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

```
> memory.limit()
[1] 8019
> memory.size()
[1] 1147.37
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplificando mucho, la respuesta sería:

- Instalar más memoria física, por lo que dices, necesitas algo más 1 TB
- Contratar algún servicio en la nube que ofrezca semejante cantidad de memoria ([Amazon](https://aws.amazon.com/es/about-aws/whats-new/2016/05/now-available-x1-instances-the-largest-amazon-ec2-memory-optimized-instance-with-2-tb-of-memory/) por ejemplo)

Ahora detallando un poco más, el problema básicamente radica en que la forma de estimar el óptimo número `k` que hace `fviz_nbclust()` es calculando previamente  una matriz de distancias, la cual crece exponencialmente en función de la cantidad de observaciones. Puedes calcular eventualmente la cantidad de valores de esta matriz:

```
n <- 500000
n*(n-1)/2
[1] 124999750000
```

Reproduciendo tu problema de forma más simple:

```
tam <- c(100000, 1) # Para definir una matriz de 10.000 filas y 1 columna
m <- matrix(rnorm(tam[1]*tam[2]), ncol = tam[2])
d <- dist(m)

Error in dist(m) : cannot allocate vector of length 704982704
```

En mi caso, con un equipo mas modesto ya no puedo calcular las distancias de una matriz de 100.000 filas y una sola columna. ¿Que se puede hacer? respondiendo estrictamente las dos cosas que comenté antes, sin embargo otra aproximación al problema podría ser usar un conjunto menor de datos, es decir extraer una muestra más pequeña y manejable:

```
small_data <- data[sample(1:1000),,drop=FALSE]
fviz_nbclust(small_data, kmeans, method = "wss") +
    geom_vline(xintercept = 3, linetype = 2)
```

O bien, una forma más básica sería, aplicando directamente el modelo `kmean` sobre los datos completos con distintos números de `k` y evaluar en cada caso la suma de los cuadrados de las distancias de cada observación al centroide, que eventualmente también podríamos graficar, aunque el número `k` debería ser evaluado visualmente.

```
k.max <- 10
wss <- sapply(1:k.max, 
              function(k){kmeans(data, k, nstart=50, iter.max = 5 )$tot.withinss})
wss
plot(1:k.max, wss,
     type="b", pch = 19, frame = FALSE, 
     xlab="Number of clusters K",
     ylab="Total within-clusters sum of squares")
```

Comment: Gracias, creo que la solución más práctica será tomar una muestra, para obtener una buena idea del k óptimo, justo pensé en algún servicio en la nube ¿habrá alguno gratuito?

Comment: @googolplex, no creo que con estos requerimientos, pero Amazon, Azure (Microsoft), IBM, tienen opciones de evaluación de sus herramientas de la nube